# Psych::SyntaxError when trying to run obtvse on Mac OS X

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundle

What am i doing wrong? bundle install runs fine, ruby is at 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-darwin12.0.0]. Tried to replace psych with syck already but it throws the exact same errors.

```
rMBP:obtvse Tobias$ rails s
=> Booting Thin
=> Rails 3.2.0 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
/Users/Tobias/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:203:in `parse': 
(<unknown>): found character that cannot start any token while scanning for the next
token  at line 7 column 22 (Psych::SyntaxError)
from /Users/Tobias/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:203:in
`parse_stream'
from /Users/Tobias/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:151:in `parse'
from /Users/Tobias/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:127:in `load'
from /Users/Tobias/Dropbox/obtvse/config/initializers/config.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/Tobias/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
(...)
```

Comment: What’s line 7 of your `config.yml`? It looks like you’ve got character of some type there.

Comment: Uh, you're right. There was a  'tab' character where it does not belong.